# The Emulator Process for AVD has killed Linux

Tags: android, android-studio, archlinux

While trying to run the emulator I'm getting this error:

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API was killed

I have updated my Android Studio and everything. I have also deleted old AVD. And created new one, but still same error.

[image: error]

If I try running from run button or clicking switch android emulator I got this error

[image: error opening emulator]

I set up PATH like this in `.zshrc`

```
# Android SDK ROOT PATH
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/SDK/Android/Sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/.android\avd"
```

Thanks in advance for your help!